Lipschitz constant of projected function
Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is Lipschitz with constant $K$. Suppose I project $f$ onto orthogonal subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, say $X$ and $Y$, where $\mathbb{R}^n= X \oplus Y$ and $Y$ is the orthogonal complement of $X$. Denote the projection of $f$ onto $X$ along$Y$ $f_X$ and the projection of $f$ onto $Y$ parallel to $X$ $f_Y$, so that $f=f_X + f_Y$. I can show easily that both projections are again Lipschitz, and that each Lipschitz constant $K_X$ and $K_Y$ is less than $K$. Is it true also that $K_X+K_Y\le K$?

$n=1$, $m=2$, $f(t)=(\frac12t,\frac{\sqrt3}2t)$, $X=\Bbb R\times{0}$, $Y={0}\times\Bbb R$, you have $K=1$, $K_X=\frac12$, $K_Y=\frac{\sqrt3}2$.

@Sassatelli Giulio Sorry, I meant $n=m$ my bad. I correct the post. Are there counterexamples also with same dimension?

$g(t,s)=f(t)$, same $f$ as before, same numbers.
